# Swift: String value not passing from tableView to Other view

Tags: ios, swift

What I'm trying to do is to capture the textLabel.text of a cell in my table view controller, and pass it to a label in another view. After a lot of research here's what I have so far:

```
var valueToPass:String!

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

    // Get Cell Label
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;

    valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel!.text
    println("\(valueToPass) is captured")
    performSegueWithIdentifier("theSegue", sender: self)

}



override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "theSegue") {


        var viewController = segue.destinationViewController as FinalView

        viewController.resto = valueToPass
    }

}
```

And here is the code for FinalView, which is where the variable 'resto' lives:

```
class FinalView: UIViewController{

  var resto:String!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      println("the restoname is: \(resto)")
      restoLabel.text = resto

}


     @IBOutlet var restoLabel: UILabel!

}
```

but when I check whether everything worked correctly, this is the result of my println statements:

```
the restoname is: nil
You selected cell #13!
Tanad Thai is captured
```

Why is the string 'Tanad Thai' not passing over to 'rest' in the FinalView class? I really appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done an excellent job instrumenting your code, but you need to think about what you have learned. Look at the output of your instrumentation:

```
the restoname is: nil
You selected cell #13!
Tanad Thai is captured
```

That output proves that FinalView's `viewDidLoad` is being called *before* the table view controller's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called. Thus, you cannot use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to set a value on which `viewDidLoad` depends! You need to find an *earlier* moment. Personally, I would suggest doing all the work in `prepareForSegue`.

Also, I'm a little worried that you may be performing the segue *twice* - once in the storyboard and once in code. If you have set up the segue to emanate from the cell in the storyboard, you do not need to call `performSegueWithIdentifier` - it will be called automatically.

Comment: This did it! All i did was move what I had in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and moved it to preparedForSegue. Also got rid of the performSegueWIthIdentifier. Thanks!